# Remote desktop into Virtual Machine on Ubuntu Server through a Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I'm trying to remote desktop into a Windows virtual machine that is running on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I'm on OS X Yosemite and I can't figure out how to do it.

I downloaded the app [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12) but I think I'm using it wrong. It keeps saying "Connection Refused". I enter a connection name > put ip of Ubuntu Server in PC Name > Add virtual machine ip under gateway > enter my username and password for Ubuntu Server. Is there anything wrong there?

Is there another way to do it? My Ubuntu Server doesn't have a desktop environment (just terminal), so I can't use the rdesktop package. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd guess it ought to be the other way round, You're trying to connect to the Win VM, using the Ubuntu as gateway. I'd even try it without the gateway at all, just look for the Win VM by its IP address. The Win OS needs to have RDC enabled in the firewall, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you've bridged your connection from your host to your virtual machine (see http://aql.ink/sw0BMNbs.png), it will appear on the network, as long as your host machine has an active connection on the specified interface and it's using DHCP. From there, you'd RDP directly to your virtual machine's IP.